# How can I create ws inbound-gateway with Java DSL in Spring integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have the following ws inbound gateway. How can I do this configuration with Spring Integration Java 8 DSL?

```
<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="ws-inbound-gateway"
                        request-channel="ws-request-channel"
                        reply-channel="ws-response-channel"
                        error-channel="ws-error-channel"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunally I don't find a first level support for this kind of inbound gateway, however you can fix this as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway() {
            SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway simpleWebServiceInboundGateway = new SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway();
            // your inbound configurtion
            .....

            return simpleWebServiceInboundGateway;
        }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(){
            return IntegrationFlows.from(SimpleWebServiceInboundGateway())
            // your pipeline
            .....
                    .get();
        }   
    }
```

in your maven pom don't forget this dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I hope that this can help you

Comment: Valerio, how would you go about configurating an outbound web service channel in the same way?